# Use R behind a proxy on EC2 instance

Tags: r, http, amazon-ec2, proxy, ifconfig

I am trying to use R behind a proxy on an AWS EC2 instance but I don’t know how to check if I am actually behind this proxy.
My proxy uses ***port 80*** and requires a password ***“pwd:123.ABC”*** to work properly (illustrative).

```
proxy_http_url <- "http://123.123.123:80"
proxy_https_url <- proxy_http_url
Sys.setenv(http_proxy = proxy_http_url, http_proxy_user = "pwd:123.ABC", https_proxy = proxy_https_url, https_proxy_user = " pwd:123.ABC ", ftp_proxy = proxy_http_url)  

download.file(url, destfile ='get_data.html', quiet = FALSE)
```

To see if my IP adress would change, I did the following:

```
url <- "http://ipinfo.io/ip"
download.file(url, destfile ='ip_test.html', quiet = FALSE)
ip_test <- website_url%>%html_nodes(xpath="//body")%>%html_text()
ip_test <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(ip_test), nrow=length(ip_test), byrow=T))
```

But the IP adress does not change, even after applying again the Sys.setenv()function.
So I am guessing I am not behind the proxy I want to use.

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Help much appreciated !

EDIT:

Comment: `ifconfig` system command shows you only your internal IPs. By internal I mean those are assigned to your instance by DHCP server of your VPC. In order to check your IP that is visible to external sites, you need to request any service similar to http://ipinfo.io/ip after you set the proxy in your R script and check the returned HTML.

Comment: Hello, I scraped the outcoming IP of ipinfo.io/ip and the ip is still the same one, not my proxy, so my code does work.

Comment: can you update your code sample above with getting the contents of ipinfo?

Comment: I just edited now.

Comment: what does `Sys.getenv("http_proxy")` return after you download the file? What if you replace `download.file` with `getURL`?

Comment: Sys.getenv("http_proxy") outputs "http://123.123.123:80". But does that necessarily means the proxy is working? How do I know the password was entered correctly?

Comment: Actually, I then try to use `download.file` and I got an error: 'HTTP Response code said error'. So I am guessing authentification is not working. I really do not know how to set up this proxy.

Comment: But you said it used to work with proxy earlier? In order to debug we need the full response, headers and body. What does it show if you prepend the `download.file` call with `options(internet.info = 0)`?

Comment: Sorry it is a typo mistake, I meant "so my code does not work". Please find below the output error details.

Comment: Do you want to try using httr library and set the proxy with username and password using `use_proxy` function?

Comment: here is my attempt: `pre_url <- POST(url, use_proxy(proxy_http_url , port=80, username = 'user1', password = '123.ABC'), verbose())` .  but don't know how to test if I am really behind the proxy with a validated password...

Comment: just change it to GET and use ipinfo.io/ip as the `url` and see the returned result

Answer (score 0):

So if I take *Soundcloud* where scraping is authorized. Here is the output I have which tells me my proxy is not authenticated:

> - trying URL 'https://soundcloud.com/liluzivert/new-patek'
> - Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 80 (#0)
> - Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to soundcloud.com:443
>     CONNECT soundcloud.com:443 HTTP/1.1 Host: soundcloud.com:443 User-Agent: R (3.4.1 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)
> - Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> - Error in download.file(url, destfile = "scrape_website.html", quiet =
>     FALSE) :    cannot open URL
>     'https://soundcloud.com/liluzivert/new-patek'
> - In addition: Warning message: In download.file(url, destfile = "scrape_ website.html",
>     quiet = FALSE) :   URL 'https://soundcloud.com/liluzivert/new-patek':
>     **status was 'HTTP response code said error'**
> - **HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required** < Server: squid/3.5.23 < Mime-Version: 1.0 <
>     Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2018 11:52:41 GMT < Content-Type:
>     text/html;charset=utf-8 < Content-Length: 4 < X-Squid-Error:
>     ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0 < Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="login" <
>     X-Cache: MISS from s_sh96 < Via: 1.1 s_sh96 (squid/3.5.23)
> - Connection: keep-alive < > * Ignore 4 bytes of response-body
> - The requested URL returned error: 407
> - Connection #0 to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX left intact